# Azure IoT hub simple publish-subcribe communication

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I’m new to Microsoft’s Azure IoT Hub and MQTT/AMQP communication in general and I am trying to establish simple communication between my raspberry pi and a Ubunutu VM running on my computer. I intended on using my pi by as a client to publish messages to a service running on my VM that simply echoes the message contents to std out. After reading all the literature on the Azure website/github page I’m having trouble figuring out the best way to do this. Is it possible to host a service on your local network? Are the iotHub service client samples on the SDK meant to be used as services or as clients intended to communicate with existing services on Azure (SQL databases, webserver, etc)? I was able to send messages to my IoT Hub portal with azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_mqtt.c sample but couldn’t figure out where to include the topic my message was getting published to. I would really appreciate any help/input.

Thanks

Comment: I agree with @Olivier Bloch. As for including topic, [since IoT Hub is not a general purpose pub-sub messaging broker, it only supports the documented topic names and topic filters.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub is just a message channel, and it does not handle messages.

For device side (raspberry pi), you use a device SDK to send D2C messages with MQTT, and it works. For service side (Ubuntu VM), you need **Event Hub SDK** to receive D2C messages sent by raspberry pi (Why Event Hub? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zhqqitest/2017/03/18/do-not-make-it-a-mess-why-therere-so-many-endpoints-in-iot-hub/).

Also, IoT Hub supports MQTT on device side ONLY, that is to say, you cannot connect to IoT Hub with MQTT on service side (Ubuntu VM), but you need AMQP.

You may have another question, then what is the AMQP topic to listen for D2C messages on service side? It's `/<compatibleName>/ConsumerGroups/<ConsumerGroups>/Partitions/<PartitionID>`.

- compatibleName: IoT Hub Event Hub-compatible name (what a mess :-S), you can find it from Azure portal (Endpoints – Built-in endpoints – Events)
- ConsumerGroups: You can find it from Azure portal, `$Default` by default
- PartitionID: Partition ID, you can get it when you connect to the Event Hub with AMQP, it's a number, ususally start from `0`

If you don't want to call AMQP directly, you can simply use Event Hub SDK on Ubuntu VM with IoT Hub connection string (NOT Event Hub-compatible endpoint or Event Hub-compatible name, the Event Hub SDK will do that for you).

Answer (score 2):

The Azure IoT **device** SDKs are meant to build device applications that will connect and communicate with the Azure IoT Hub service which lives in the Azure Cloud.

The Azure IoT **service** SDKs are meant to build applications that will be used to configure, monitor and interact with an instance of the Azure IoT Hub service running in the Azure Cloud.

If you are looking for a simple solution for establishing a local device to device or device to server communication leveraging MQTT, you can look into MQTT broker solutions out there.

Now if you want to leverage an IoT Cloud to manage devices, easily secure and authenticate them, upload telemetry to the Cloud at a high throughput and take advantage of advanced analytics services in the Cloud (Big Data, Machine Learning,...), then Azure IoT Hub is for you.